# Ignore previous values sent by a CwlSignal

Tags: reactive-programming, cwlsignal

I have a `continuous` parent signal that I derive various other signals from. Most of the subscribers are fine with the “continuous” semantics, meaning they do want to receive the last value upon subscribing. But with some subscribers I just want to receive the future values, no initial ones. Example:

```
import CwlSignal

let (input, signal) = Signal<Int>.create { s in s.continuous() }

input.send(value: 1)
input.send(value: 2)

let e1 = signal.subscribeValues { val in
    print("A: \(val)")
}

let e2 = signal.subscribeValues { val in
    print("B: \(val)")
}

input.send(value: 3)
input.close()
```

This prints:

```
A: 2
B: 2
A: 3
B: 3
```

Now I would like the second subscription not to receive the initial value, ie. the output should look like this:

```
A: 2
A: 3
B: 3
```

Is it possible to get that kind of behaviour without tweaking the parent signal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using `multicast` signals, quote [reply from the library author](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlSignal/issues/14#issuecomment-310292683):

```
let (input, multicastSignal) = Signal<Int>.create { s in s.multicast() }
let continuousSignal = multicastSignal.continuous()

input.send(value: 1)
input.send(value: 2)

let e1 = continuousSignal.subscribeValues { val in
    print("A: \(val)")
}

let e2 = multicastSignal.subscribeValues { val in
    print("B: \(val)")
}

input.send(value: 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used CwlSignal, but it [looks like it has a `skip` operator](https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlSignal/blob/master/Sources/CwlSignal/CwlSignalReactive.swift#L1218) like most reactive frameworks. Does this work?

```
let e2 = signal.skip(1).subscribeValues { val in
    print("B: \(val)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately that would only work for signals that already received a value, for empty signals it would skip the first value received _after subscribing_.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an initial value when you call `continuous` to ensure you never have an empty signal? Otherwise, you might be out of luck. I haven't used CwlSignal, but Matt's introductory blog post makes it sound like it's a foundational feature of the framework that a signal can't be different things to different subscribers: the handling of old values must be defined in order to get a `SignalMulti`. And since operators have no way of knowing if incoming values are actually old buffered values, I'm not sure you can work around it. Anyway, good luck!